# Outputting odd or even posts in PHP with different parent wrappers -- Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Here's what I am trying to accomplish:

I want to output different posts depending on whether they are odd or even with different parent wrappers for the odd posts and the even posts.  For example, the even posts may be outputted to a parent with a class of `evenWrapper` and the odd posts may be outputted to a parent with a class of `oddWrapper`.

I get the overall theory behind using the `modulus` operator.  Where I am getting stuck is actually wrapping the even or odd posts in different parent wrappers.  Here is what I have so far:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ):
$c = 0;
?>


<div class="six columns alpha">

<?php 
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

    if($c % 2 == 0) : ?>

        <?php /* posts with even numbers are outputted here */ ?>

<?php   
    endif;
$c++;
endwhile;

?>

</div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

The above code works fine for outputting even posts.  As you can see, the parent wrapper is around the `while` loop and checks with an `if` statement using the `modulus` operator.  My first guess would be to create an `else` statement and wrap a different parent around them if they aren't even.  But I run into the problem of it being caught in the `while` loop and outputting the parent wrapper each time.

How would I proceed from here to output even posts into another parent container??  Do I have to make another `while` loop?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not fully up to speed on the WordPress API so there may or may not be a better way to get post details, but this should work regardless:

```
<?php
    $oddPosts = array();
    $evenPosts = array();
    $i = 0;
?>
<?while(have_posts()) : the_post()?>
<?
    $post = the_content(); // etc...
    if(++$i % 2 == 0) {
        array_push($evenPosts, $post);
    } else {
        array_push($oddPosts, $post);
    }
?>
<?endwhile;?>

<div class="wrapper odd">
    <?foreach($oddPosts as $post):?>
        <?= $post ?>
    <?endforeach?>
</div>
<div class="wrapper even">
    <?foreach($evenPosts as $post):?>
        <?= $post ?>
    <?endforeach?>
</div>
```

Comment: Ahh, very interesting.  Now, the `$post` variable, I'm assuming, holds all of the post PHP code?  Is it acceptable to have a variable with something that big?

Comment: That's something you'd have to see for yourself. I have no clue what the result of WordPress' `the_content()` function does exactly. Note however that you can store a heck of a lot of html (as plaintext anyway) in a meg of ram and you probably have at least 8 or 16 mess available per request. I doubt you'd run into trouble unless you have more than a few hits per second but as always; YMMV

Comment: This really helped me, just a note for anyone who copies this code - the second foreach loop should start with $evenPosts, not $oddPosts again :)

Answer (score 0):

It's really simple, actually. And yes, you need an `else` statement too. Here's an example:

```
<?php if ($c % 2 === 0): ?>
<div class="evenWrapper">
<?php else: ?>
<div class="oddWrapper">
<?php endif; ?>
...
</div>
```

You can also do something like this:

```
<?php
$class = $c % 2 === 0 ? 'evenWrapper' : 'oddWrapper';
?>
<div class="<?php echo $class; ?>">
</div>
```

Comment: Makes sense, but the thing that is driving the counter is the `while` loop.  I can't put a different wrapper in a `while` loop because it will keep spitting out the parent wrapper.

Comment: So what you're saying is that you only want one of each wrapper with all the appropriate corresponding to the wrapper posts inside? I suppose that's possible. But it might take 2 loops even if you're only querying the database once. Any reason why you want it that way? I mean if you assign the class to each post, it's completely fine you know. You just need to style them with CSS according to what you want.

Comment: Basically, I am trying to put every other post into two wrappers on a front page of a blog I am creating.  So, the posts could be side by side to each other.  I figured that was the best way to go about it.

Comment: Yes, I understand what you mean. I think it's better if you give each post a class (whether it's odd or even) and style it so the whole thing looks like the way you want. That's the simplest solution the problem.

Comment: While you're right and I get what you're saying, it doesn't solve my problem.  I need to wrappers side by side so I can stack posts neatly underneath each other.  Doing it by post doesn't allow me to style it the way I want to.

Answer (score 0):

just use $wp_query->current_post to get the current index position of the post:

```
<?php if (($wp_query->current_post) % 2) $class="evenWrapper"; else $class="oddWrapper"; ?>

<article <?php post_class($class); ?>>
 ...content here ...
</article>
```